# Solr search all

Tags: solr

I add to solr index: "bull", "bulgarie", "bulltin", "bullhead" . When I search by "bul" it gives me only article with "bull"

How should schema.xml be configured to get all results with "bull*" example : "bull", "bulgarie", "bulltin", "bullhead"?

This is the current configuration in **schema.xml**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax look for wildcard queries

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to search for "bul*"? See http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F for the wildcard support in Lucene, which I guess will be very very similar to the Solr one.

Answer (score 0):

Solr supports wildcard queries. That is how range queries work as well. By just using it this way your problem should be solved.

fieldname:bul*